# Understanding StateFromReducersMapObject type in Redux

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-generics

I am trying to read the Redux source code and I am stuck at the below type definition in `src/types/reducers.ts`

```js
/**
 * Infer a combined state shape from a `ReducersMapObject`.
 *
 * @template M Object map of reducers as provided to `combineReducers(map: M)`.
 */
export type StateFromReducersMapObject<M> = M extends ReducersMapObject<
  any,
  any
>
  ? { [P in keyof M]: M[P] extends Reducer<infer S, any> ? S : never }
  : never
```

I am stuck at:

```js
M extends ReducersMapObject<
  any,
  any
>
  ? { [P in keyof M]: M[P] extends Reducer<infer S, any> ? S : never }
  : never
```

There is a `?` in this line. This look like a ternary operation.

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

[Here is the full source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/types/reducers.ts). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` is a conditional type [introduced in TypeScript 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types).

For example:

```js
T extends U ? X : Y
```

In this simplified example, if `T extends U` (aka `T` is assignable to `U`) then T is of type `X`. Otherwise, if not, `T` is of type `Y`.

So in you're case of:

```js
M extends ReducersMapObject<
  any,
  any
>
  ? { [P in keyof M]: M[P] extends Reducer<infer S, any> ? S : never }
  : never
```

If `M extends ReducersMapObject<any, any>` (aka `M` is assignable to `ReducersMapObject<any, any>`) then `M` is `{ [P in keyof M]: M[P] extends Reducer<infer S, any> ? S : never }`, otherwise `M` is `never`.

In this case, it's a nested conditional type, so with `M[P] extends Reducer<infer S, any> ? S : never` is also evaluated. So if `M[P]` is assignable to `Reducer<infer S, any>` then `M[P]` is `S`, else it's `never`.